# Is it possible to set multiple callback functions for a given event with GTK (Python)?

Tags: python, callback, gtk3

If so, how would this be done? If not, is there a conventional way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I don't use GTK3, but you can certainly bind multiple callbacks to an event in GTK2, and they will be called in the order they were bound. Alternatively, you might find it better to just create a single callback that calls your multiple functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, PM 2Ring.

For posterity, the answer is that you *can* bind multiple callbacks to a signal in GTK3. They will be called in the order they were bound in.